# Highly Curved Parabolic Makeup Mirror?

Tags: bathroom, mirror

I saw a highly curved parabolic mirror that I had never seen before in a hotel I visited recently.

It was on an arm in the bathroom and unfortunately I didn't think to take a picture at the time.

It looked very similar to this and gave very high magnification: 
[image: Parabolic Mirror]

The curve of the mirror was very prominent, so much so that it almost looked like the capital "U" character here, but not quite parallel of course.

What are these class of mirrors called? I would imagine that they have a different name because I can't find them anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps “custom”?

Comment: @statueuphemism Possibly, but this might not be true. Perhaps I'll give them a call.

Comment: search - Makeup mirror

Comment: which hotel did you visit? .... there may be pictures online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is not limited to locating a vanity mirror of this sort (I failed to do so), you may discover that your objective can be gained by searching for parabolic trough reflector or parabolic trough mirror. The returns I found from those terms cover mostly solar collectors designed to focus light on thermally related energy systems. Some of the links also point to engineering documents regarding design and construction.

An advantage of such a design in thermal energy collection is that it can be aligned in one direction and rotated on the long axis to provide near-continuous exposure to the sun.